# 確実にファイルを削除するコマンドは？

Tags: linux

`rm text.txt`

で削除したファイルは実は完全削除されたわけではなく復元ができると知りました。

ファイルを完全にファイルを削除するコマンドはあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS7で確認したところ`shred`コマンドがインストールされているようでした。`-u`オプション付きで削除ができますね。

> shred - ファイルを上書きし、その内容が分からないようにする
>          (追加でファイルの削除も可能)

ちなみにMacOSXでは、`rm`に`-P`オプションをつけると似たようなことができるみたいです。

> -P          Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times,
>                    first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are
>                    deleted.

Comment: CentOS と MacOS の両方のコマンドがうれしかったです :)

Answer (score 3):

rmしたファイルは、ファイルとしての管理情報が消されるだけで、ファイルのあったディスク領域の内容はそのままです。完全に消すには、ランダムに上書きするshredコマンドをかけた後でrmするとよいかと思います。

```
$ shred text.txt
$ rm text.txt
```

または、shredコマンドに-uオプションを付けるとファイルの削除もやってくれます。

```
$ shred -u text.txt
```