# ディレクトリごと完全に削除するコマンドはありますか？

Tags: linux

以下の様なディレクトリがあり、ルートの `exile/` から完全にすべてのファイルとディレクトリを削除するコマンドはありますか？

```
exile/
exile/members/
exile/members/Hiro_Hiroyuki.txt
exile/members/Toshio_Matsumoto.txt
exile/members/Üsa_Yoshihiro.txt
exile/members/...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「指定したディレクトリ内の全てファイルを削除する方法」という意味であれば、以下のコマンドをオススメします。

```
rm -rf exile
```

オプション指定の `-r` (recursive) は再帰的な削除を、`-f` (force) は警告メッセージを抑制するために使用します。

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS**

`rm -rP exile/`

**Linux**
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/21089/14041

`rm -rf exile/`

で完全削除できるはずです。

オプション説明

```
-r 指定ディレクトリ以下をすべて削除
-P データを３回書き換えてファイルを完全消去(**MacOS専用**)
```

こちらから引用しました

> 「確実にファイルを削除するコマンドは？」
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/21082/5505

Comment: リンク先にも書いてますが`-P`はOSXを含むBSD系rmコマンド特有のオプションなのでLinux環境では使えないかと思います

Comment: @kosh そのとおりでした。